# Why does await never return?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm seeing an await that never seems to return. Here's the sample code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _status;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _status = "Ready";

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
        }
    }

    private void OnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Status = "Running...";

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        StartProcessing();
    }

    private void OnStop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private async void StartProcessing()
    {
        try
        {
            await new Task(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Expected: {e.Message}");
        }

        Status = "Done!";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

What happens is OnStart gets called, it sets status to "Running...", then calls StartProcessing. Five seconds lapse, however I never see the status get set to "Done!"

If I call OnStop, then the task is cancelled and I see the "Done!" status.

I'm guessing I'm creating a task as well as the task created by async/await but it's hanging or deadlocking?

Here's the WPF XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="CancellationSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Cancellation Test" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Width="70" Margin="5" Click="OnStart">Start</Button>
        <Button Width="70" Margin="5" Click="OnStop">Stop</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
    <Grid></Grid>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: As a best practice use `async Task` as opposed to `async void`.

Comment: You did not start the task. Please use Task.Run()

Comment: @StephenWilson While that's better practice 99% of time, you need to use `async void` on `Event Handlers`, which is what the OP is using

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto using `async void` for is valid for event handlers, but `async Task` could / should be used for the `StartProcessing()` method.

Comment: [Never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a `new Task` but not starting it, so it never finishes. Instead use [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) and `await` on that.

```
await Task.Run(() => { });
```

Consider also using [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `Thread.Sleep` so that you don't block the current thread,

Comment: If I directly replace Thread.Sleep with Task.Delay it creates another task so that main task completes immediately and I see "Done!" as soon as I hit Start. If I remove all the extra fluff and replace it with await Task.Delay(5000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token); it works much better!

Comment: @imekon of course, that's how you are supposed to use Task.Delay, without an extra Task just for wrapping

Answer (score 5):

You want to avoid using `async void` on methods. Update `StartProcessing` to return `Task` and also you should use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`

```
private async Task StartProcessing() {
    try {
        await Task.Delay(5000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    } catch (TaskCanceledException e) {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Expected: {e.Message}");
    }
    Status = "Done!";
}
```

Next if `OnStart` is in fact an event handler it is the one exception where `async void` is allowed. Update `OnStart` to be async and then await the now awaitable `StartProcessing`

```
private async void OnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Status = "Running...";

    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await StartProcessing();
}
```

Finally I would suggest reading

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming By Stephen Cleary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

to get a better understanding of how to use async/await